# Calculating percentage saved in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two `Product` objects. The first is the Monthly product which is used as the baseline for the pricing. The second is the Annual product which is billed every 12 months and has a discounted price.

What is the best way in ruby to calculate the percentage saved by picking the Annual pricing?

```
#<Product name: "Monthly", interval: 1.0, price: 50.0>
#<Product name: "Annually", interval: 12.0, price: 540.0>
```

Comment: show us the class body also

Comment: The class is just an empty ActiveRecord model as these are simply attributes/columns on the Product class.

Comment: As you only tagged as Ruby.. so I asked. :D

Comment: I thought about tagging it Rails but thought that the class was simple enough that it didn't warrant mentioning Rails as they're just attributes.

Comment: Where is the discount? `12 * 40 = 480` is cheaper than `540`.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should be 50, not 40. Too early to type I guess :/

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not a Ruby question. That's a math question at the level of elementary school.

Comment: Then please fix it (40=>50).

Comment: Updated the question to show correct value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
discount = annual.price - (monthly.price * (1.0 * annual.interval / monthly.interval))

discount_percentage = 100.0 - (100.0 * annual.price / annual.interval) / (monthly.price / monthly.interval)
```

Output:

```
+12.5 %
```

So you pay more annually with the example you provided ;)